# Bootstrap affix won't change active tab

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

The code is written by a former front-end developer of my company. After he left, I was asked to edit this page. When I finished working on CSS, I found the affix which formerly worked, will always activate the last li element. I tried a lot of ways but have no idea why this is happening.

Example code:

```
<ul id="myNav" class="nav nav-tabs nav-stacked">
  <li><a href="#section-1">关于Speed Dating</a></li>
  <li><a href="#section-2">活动流程</a></li>
  <li><a href="#section-3">成功案例</a></li>
  <li><a href="#section-4">往期回顾</a></li>
  <li><a href="#section-5">地点</a></li>
  <li><a href="#section-6">合作伙伴</a></li>
</ul>
......
<h2 id="section-1">关于Speed Dating</h2>
<h2 id="section-2">关于Speed Dating</h2>
......
```

The whole code is on [CodePen](http://codepen.io/kxxoling/pen/raMWEL)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found it's because the former marked with attributes `data-spy="scroll" data-target="#myScrollspy"` was now on a div element.

I deleted the body tag because the former HTML has two `body` tag, the first one is set in the base template, and the second one is written in HTML to bind bootstrap affix. So bootstrap affix doesn't work after I change the second `body` tag to `div`.

TL,NR: It fixed after I add attributes `data-spy="scroll" data-target="#myScrollspy"` to body element.